# How to join different speed limit to one segment in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis

I need to join speed limit to a network. However, in the network data, some of the segments have different speed limit. For example, a street has two different speed limit in the beginning and in the end. Because of that I get this error:
SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Do you have any suggestions?

This is my current query:

```
ALTER TABLE speed_signs_geob
  ADD COLUMN speed SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 50;
UPDATE speed_signs_geob
   SET speed =   CASE
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 10 KM/H' THEN 10
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 20' THEN 20
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 30' THEN 30
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 30 SECTEUR' THEN 30
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 40' THEN 40
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 40 SECTEUR' THEN 40
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 50' THEN 50
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 60' THEN 60
     WHEN description_rpa = 'MAXIMUM 70' THEN 70
     ELSE 50
  END
;
```

```
UPDATE mtl_road_network
   SET speed = (SELECT (speed)  FROM speed_signs_geob s WHERE s.seg_id = seg_id);
```

Comment: Please show expected result. It is not clear how you want to assign two values to one field.

Comment: What I want to do is to assign one maximum speed to each row. I'm so new to Postgresql and I don't know how I can do that. 

The error above is what I get:  SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: Showing your query is good, but insufficient. Please post example data in table form and table definition (ddl) (or better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)) and the expected results of that data. Also as text - **no images**.